# dojo ListItem: display style changes on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I apologize, but I'm not able to provide a working jsFiddle snippet. I will update the question if I understand how to put the code below in it.

Using `dojox/mobile` I populate an `EdgeToEdgeStoreList` with custom `ListItems`. Some code:

### html (jade)

```
div(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View")
    h1(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading") Device List
    div(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane")
        ul#list(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemRenderer: DeviceListItem, select: 'single'")
```

### js

```
var store;
var list = registry.byId("listDevices");
var devices = JSON.parse("a string received from server");

store = new Memory({data: devices, idProperty: "label"});
list.setStore(store);
```

### DeviceListItem

```
define([
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (ListItem, TemplatedMixin, declare) {
    var template =
        "<div class='deviceDone${done}'>" +
        "       ${id} - <div style='display: inline-block;' data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div>" +
        "       <div class='deviceCategory'>${category}</div>" +
        "</div>";

    TemplatedListItem = declare("DeviceListItem",
        [ListItem, TemplatedMixin], {
            id: "",
            label: "",
            category: "",
            done: "false",
            templateString: template
        }
    );
});
```

It works fine, that is I will see my custom `ListItems`.
But if I resize the window (on desktop browsers) or change orientation (on mobile ones) only the `${id}` field remains visible. The others (`label` and `category`) disappear. The behavior is the same in all browsers (that I tried).

After debugging I discovered the following. Before any resize the actual html of a `ListItem` looks like this:

```
<div id="item1728" class="deviceDoneFalse mblListItem mblListItemUnchecked" tabindex="0" widgetid="item1728" aria-selected="false" role="option">
    item1728 - 
    <div style="display: inline-block;" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode">n.a.</div>
    <div class="deviceCategory">General purpose</div>
</div>
```

and it's like the template string. After a resize the inner `div` becomes:

```
<div style="display: block;" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode">n.a.</div>
```

without "inline" all the layout will mess-up and thus the fields "disappear" (actually go below, behind the next row).

I wonder why this happens - the display style is hardcoded into the template strings!

Furthermore, I inspected the CSS rules at runtime, and it's not due to them, it's the html that has changed - indeed.

Answer (score 1):

ListItem (source in dojox/Mobile/ListItem.js) has the following function:

```
resize: function(){
    if(this.variableHeight){
        this.layoutVariableHeight();
    }

    // labelNode may not exist only when using a template (if not created by an attach point)
    if(!this._templated || this.labelNode){
        // If labelNode is empty, shrink it so as not to prevent user clicks.
        this.labelNode.style.display = this.labelNode.firstChild ? "block" : "inline";
    }
},
```

This function is called after a resize and as you can see sets the labelNode display style to "block".

You can replace this function when you define your DeviceListItem, keeping the original source as is but changing the display style.

Comment: I seems to work. But I thougth `labelNode` was filled with the `label` value. I mean, does not the `label` value is bind to the `labelNode`?

Comment: Yes. I suppose `this.labelNode.firstChild` is just used to check if it is empty or not.

Comment: Yes, now I understand the code, but not the intended default behavior! Anyway, reimplement this function seems to fix my needs. I'm going to do some other tests and then I'll accept your answer!